# Appeal deletion of answer

Tags: support

I'd like to appeal the deletion of this answer:

https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/16900/7017

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original answer as you posted it was clearly too opinion-based for this website. But the second version of it is fine. I restored it.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to modify it, hence the second answer that was deleted for being duplicate.